# What would cause websphere to throw this error "Unable to communicate with the messaging engine "

Tags: jms, websphere-7, webmethods

An WebMethods instance is trying to connect to the WebSphere server and WebMethods would get the following error:
(Note that the connection has been established before and has worked fine. Just from time to time the following error would show and would be good to know the reason why.)

Exception: CWSIP0471E: Unable to communicate with the messaging engine {a ...} where the destination MonthEndPIOutQueueDestination is Localised... [Linked Exception] com.ibm.websphere.sib.exception.SIResourceException: CWSIC8007E: An exception was caught from the remote server with Probe Id 3-010-0003. Exception: CWSIP0471E: Unable to communicate with the messaging engine {b ...} where the destination { c ...} is Localised..

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was happening every time there was a WAS restart. and web methods was not able to reconnect without resetting the connection settings.

Solution was to create a process in webMethods that checks every 15 minutes (depending on business requirements) and restarts the connections settings if there is no connection.